# Cybernetic pieces looted off of Kellogg: What are they for?

Tags: fallout-4

I looted a cybernetic pain inhibitor and cybernetic limb actuator off of Kellogg's body and they are worth quite a bit of caps. I can't tell, however, if they're useful for anything else... like, are they something you can give to Valentine, for instance? Or are they just sellable junk pieces?

Comment: There's another piece beside those two which gets used in the main story. Did you use that one already, or did you not pick it up?

Comment: I did get and use that one, thanks for mentioning it! It was the remaining two pieces I was wondering about, as I haven't found an apparent use for them yet. :)

Comment: I haven't found a use for those two pieces, but I'm not completely through the game yet, so I'm not gonna post that as an answer.

Comment: I'm guessing that either they are useless scrap or if you stick with the institute you can possibly get them implanted for bonuses.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pretty sure the post indicating you can have the implants installed by the Institute is a hoax.

I have completed the institute endgame (and non-radiant side quests) and talked to every named NPC in every division (nobody was killed or exiled), none of them mentions the implants when they are in my inventory and no doctors have this as an option in any sub menus.

Comment: Chosen as answer because of the stated experience with the Institute and because of confirmation that you tried dealing with the NPCs in question. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 4):

The two cybernetic items not used for the next quest are miscellaneous items and you can sell them if you want.

Comment: Someone above guessed at the possibility of using them as implants. Can you confirm that this is not an option? I'd imagine they wouldn't expect you to hold onto them for a later part of the story without any hints as to their use, but I just wanted to confirm. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Additional support of Grigoriprime's answer and further verification that the answer by Aaron is a hoax:

https://steamcommunity.com/app/377160/discussions/0/496881136916896659/

> I have spoken to every individual in the institute I can find, none
>   have made any reference to the implants. I did this both when I first
>   entered, mid-way through the last act, and again after I finished the
>   game siding with the institute.
>
> At this point, there's no reason to believe these are anything but
>   vendor trash. That being said, "needing" caps isn't something anyone
>   that's this far in the story should be thinking. Might as well hold
>   onto them, you never know.

Answer (score -6):

Yes you can indeed use the Cybernetics as implants if you stuck qith the institute.  If you have the limb actuator, you won't take any fall damage, and if you have the Pain inhibitor, you take 20% less damage from all enemies.  If you talk to a doctor from the bio section after you side with the institute, he'll offer to inplant them

Comment: Can anybody else confirm this? Those are pretty huge bonuses. Pretty much invalidates kalina's answer.

Comment: which NPC did you speak to?